I don't understand what is Network Padding
I'm building an arp spoofer in Python with scapy and I have this function to send spoofed arp packets:
def arp_spoof (dest_ip, dest_mac, source_ip):
    scapy.sendp(scapy.Ether(dst=dest_mac)/ scapy.ARP(op="is-at", psrc=source_ip, hwdst=dest_mac, pdst=dest_ip)/scapy.Padding(load="X"*18),  verbose=False)

And it works perfectly.
I'm using the sendp() method, that sends packet at layer two, so in the Ether section I added the destination mac address and then in the ARP section I added all the details to perform an ARP attack.
Then I found on the Internet that adding the Padding is a good practice while working with Network packets.
But I don't understand well what does it mean.
I searched on the Internet and I found that a packet must be 64 bits, and if it's less you add zeros with the padding.
But in this case I'm not sure what I'm doing (Am I adding X to the packet?):
scapy.Padding(load="X"*18)
Can someone explain me what is Network Padding and what does the line of code above mean?
Thank you

Network Padding:
Network Padding refers to the technique of adding extra data to a packet to ensure that it aligns with certain size requirements or constraints. This can be important for a few reasons:

Alignment: Many protocols or hardware require data to be aligned to certain boundaries (e.g., 4-byte or 8-byte boundaries) for efficiency reasons.

Minimum Length Requirements: Some protocols have minimum length requirements for packets. Padding can be used to meet these requirements.

Security and Privacy: Padding can be used to obscure the actual length of data to make it harder for attackers to infer information based on packet sizes.

Protocol Specific Needs: Certain protocols may need padding to ensure that data structures are correctly aligned or to ensure that the packet meets specific protocol standards.


Scapy Padding:
Scapy is a powerful Python library used for network packet manipulation and analysis. It allows you to create, modify, and send network packets at a low level.
In Scapy, the Padding class is used to add padding to packets. Padding can be particularly useful for manipulating packet sizes or ensuring alignment.
The Code: scapy.Padding(load="X"*18)
Here’s a breakdown of what this code does:
scapy.Padding: This class is used to add padding to a packet. Padding adds extra bytes to the packet's payload.
load="X"*18: This specifies the content of the padding. Here, "X"*18 creates a string consisting of 18 "X" characters. This string is then used as the payload for the padding.
Purpose: By creating a Padding object with load="X"*18, you are effectively adding 18 bytes of padding with each byte being the ASCII character "X".

Thank you so much! It was very helpfull!
